# Apply letter spacing in an input field only for numbers via CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm optimizing an input field of a financial services application using HTML and CSS for styling, with the ability to involve JS when necessary.

Users can enter both text (e.g client names) as well as numbers (Chargecodes / ISIN numbers) into the input field.

One painpoint adressed by users was the need to enter long numbers (16+ digits) while the font in use (condensed style) makes it hard to ensure the number was entered correctly as the numbers are way too close to each other.

I'd like to optimize this by adding increased letter-spacing to the input field, **but for numbers only**. Text inputs should remain in their base letter-spacing values.

How can I set the (preferably) CSS properties so that only numbers entered into the input field would be applied with increased letter-spacing, while letters stay in their base values?

Comment: You'd have to apply the CSS conditionally using JavaScript. Break it down into smaller issues: 1. Search "javascript check if string contains only digits", 2. Search "Apply css to input using javascript"., for example

Comment: what you try to achieve is called inputmask. It can be done with JS to whatever you like, A good list to it you find here: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask